# Prettier not auto wrap line and add bracket in React.js

Tags: reactjs, prettier

My prettier can't auto wrap line and add bracket,

before I save:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (<Layout><Component {...pageProps} /></Layout>)
}
```

I want the code become like this when save:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I tried to reinstall prettier but it didn't work, I don't know if there is something changed.
I had install ESLint too. Not sure is it the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in my User > setting.json

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
```

I delete it and then work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure your Vscode too,
in Vscode do the following:

1. Go to settings and search for on save.
2. Then check the `Editor: Format On Save` to active
3. then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
4. then choose the `Format document` or `Format document (forced)`

Two cases are possible either formatter not configured and you'll configure it using the dialog that pops up or you're all set oh and don't forget to<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> => `Reload window`

Comment: I found that I can autocomplete with .ts files but not with js files

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for your help